# multimple select2 with laravel vue js not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, jquery-select2

i want to make dynamic form .so for that i tried foreach loop .everything going fine without select options. For making classname or id name  unique i want place a index value but cant not place index value.take a look below:

```
                            <div class="form-group m-form__group row "  v-for="(pack,index) in packs">
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <label>SKU: @{{ index }}</label>
                                    <input v-model="pack.sku" type="text" name="name" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="SKU">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <label>Unit:</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2 @{{ index }}"  name="unit" v-model="pack.unit" >
                                        <option value="0">KG</option>
                                        <option value="1">ML</option>
                                        <option value="2">Liter</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <label>Size:</label>
                                    <input v-model="pack.size" type="number" name="name" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Size">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <label>Barcode:</label>
                                    <input v-model="pack.barcode" type="number" name="barcode" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Barcode">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: code you provide your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to reload select2.

html markup:

```
<select class="form-control select2 @{{ index }}"  name="unit" v-model="pack.unit" id="unit">
  <option value="0">KG</option>
  <option value="1">ML</option>
  <option value="2">Liter</option>
</select>
```

Vuejs code:

```
...
components: {

},
mounted() {
  setTimeOut(() => {
    let unit = $('#unit'); // or document.querySelector('#unit');
    unit.select2();
  }, 100);
},
```